# Blech using a griddle

Tags: shabbat, cooking-bishul

Is it permissible to perform shehiya using a griddle as a blech on Shabbos, where one uses the griddle regularly during the week to cook on - adjusting the flame all the time during its regular use?

Comment: The idea of a Blech is to be a reminder that it’s shabbos and not turn the fire up and down. If it’s exactly as it is during the week, how would it work as a reminder. (Reb Moshe held a Blech needs to cover the knobs for this reason)

Comment: @Chatzkel But then if you always use a *blech* during the week you couldn't use on on Shabbos?

Comment: @pcoz I actually saw somewhere that if someone always uses a Blech during the week, he can’t use it in Shabbos. I’ll try to locate it again.

Comment: It’s called derech bishul and would be assur. Much like the reason that a crock pot would need an additional layer as a Blech even though there’s no open flame

Comment: @Chatzkel This seems to be *nistar* by the *poskim* who say you do not need a *blech* for an electric hotplate?

Comment: I think the hotplate and crockpots are problems of hatmanah, not shehiyah. But I agree with Chatzkel. The point of a blech is that you have no intention to adjust the fire, therefore you covered it. A griddle has nothing to do with that concept. If a griddle works, why not the regular grates on the stove?

Comment: @Chatzkel first off - Reb Moshe holds specifically that you do NOT need to cover the knobs. Reb Aahron says you do; Reb Moishe is choilek. 
Second - even though a person uses his griddle to cook directly on it - still no one uses it with a pot, unlike stove grates that are used for both.

Comment: @pcoz a hot plate is not used for cooking only to keep warm. That’s why there’s no issue

Comment: @N.T. I was referring to the flat crock pots not the insert ones

Comment: @Chatzkel the simple answer to your first comment is it wouldn't actually be helpful for him but it would still be kosher since that's chazal's enactment, and we don't worry about weirdos who cook in weird ways during the week. No need to make up new gzeiros.

Comment: @doubleAA true, however I did actually see someplace that if someone used a Blech on Yom Tov because he only left on one flame and wants to spread out the heat, then there might be a problem with just leaving it there for shabbos. I don’t recall where it was though

Comment: @Chatzkel We use a hotplate for cooking on holidays.

Comment: A blech is a covering meant to show you have no intention of using the fire. A griddle is not.

Comment: @N.T. how do you know a blech needs special intention? If the coals in my hearth are scattered by wind which also blows leaves on them, can I not use them for shabbat before adjusting then lishmah like schach on a sukkah?

Comment: Can anyone site any sources?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.36b.3-6?lang=bi